# How can I remove a paused app for my iphone 4?

Tags: ios, applications

[image]

I want to delete that camera 360 app after I paused it but when I long pressed the app, yes the X mark was there but it is not deleting. What should I do? Please help me. I'm new in using an iphone. And another thing, I'm still not jailbreaking it. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the iPhone?  That usually works for stuck apps.

Answer (score 1):

If reboot doesn't work then try troubleshooting, I would do this:

- Quit app store
- Start app store and go to app and try canceling or re-downloading.
- Toggle Airplane Mode and try again
- Then reboot